# Can't set text on text view in dialog fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, dialogfragment, material-dialog

I have a dialog fragment and I use `databinding` to bind views.

I can't set text on a text view after the dialog is created.

Here is my code :

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var layout : FragmentMyDialogBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        layout = FragmentMyDialogBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return layout.root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {


        layout = FragmentMyDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()))

        layout.textView.text = "Initial text"

        layout.button.setOnClickListener{
        
        layout.textView.text = "Text changed"
        
        Log.wtf("Text","${layout.textView.text}")

        // Log shows the changed text but it is not visible on the ui.
        
        }
        

        val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext(), R.style.RoundShapeTheme)


        builder.setView(layout.root)

        return builder.create()
    }

}
```

Log shows the changed text but it is not visible on the UI.

Does anybody have a solution for this ?

Comment: Maybe try avoiding the `onCreateView` override as well? Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested your code and it is resolved by removing the `onCreateView()`.. You already use `onCreateDialog()` and it's enough for setting the binding object.

The layout is inflated twice, and probably the `textView` gets changed on the layout that is not on the UI. That is probably because the `onCreateView()` gets called after `onCreateDialog()`. So, when you change the text in the onCreateDialog() inflated layout the change is not appeared because the inflated layout by `onCreateView()` is laid on top of it.

Comment: I thought overriding onCreateView() is a required thing.

Comment: It is necessary in normal fragments.. Not in dialogFragments

Answer (score 1):

In **onCreateDialog()** method set the custom views by the following code:

> public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
> binding = DialogLayoutBinding
>           .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext())); AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
> builder.setView(binding.getRoot());
>
> binding.dialogTextView.setText("I am Dialog's TextView");
>
> return builder.create(); }
> ```